# how to convert T delimited varchar date to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a datetime column which is of datatype `Varchar` with a `T` delimiter in it.

```
 declare @timestamp varchar(50)
 set @timestamp='20230421T155638.899'
 
 select cast (@timestamp as datetime2)
```

I am not able to convert this to a `Datetime` column. I tried using `Convert`, `Cast` and also `format`. I get this error every time:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How can I convert `@timestamp` to a `datetime` datatype?

Comment: It's just simply not a valid, supported date "format" - you need to have dashes in the date, and colons in the time: `set @timestamp='2023-04-21T15:56:38.899'` and since the time has digits after the comma, you need to use `select cast (@timestamp as datetime2(3))` to specify 3 digits after the comma